# Como evitar que el navegador detecte que lo esta controlando selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

estoy haciendo una macro en vba excel y con selenium con el objetivo de automatizar un proceso, resulta que ya logre que vba me abra el navegador, ya sea chrome. edge o firefox, pero al momento de abrirlo me aparece el siguiente mensaje en el navegador.

[image: Navegador mostrando que esta siendo controlado por un software]

El problema con esto es que cuando me carga la pagina y le envió los datos a consultar enseguida me pide que valide un captcha, pero esto no es eficiente ya que los datos que tengo que consultar en esta pagina son muchos, pero cuando abro la misma pagina de manera manual y le pongo los datos no me pide resolver el captcha, el código que uso para hacer esto es el siguiente:

```
    Sub obtenerDatos()
        Dim driver As New WebDriver
        Dim valor As WebElement 
        driver.Start "Chrome"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
       'Envio la pagina al navegador
        driver.Get "https://fcm.org.co/simit/#/home-public"
       'Busco el control para ingresarle el documento a consultar
        Set valor = driver.FindElementByName("txtBusqueda")
        valor.SendKeys 72333632
       'Busco el boton para que ejecute la consulta en el sitio web
        Set valor = driver.FindElementById("consultar")
        valor.Click
    End Sub
```

He buscando como saltar esta comprobación pero no he encontrado como hacerlo en vba excel, si alguien me pudiera ayudar les agradecería mucho ya que como les comente son muchos los datos a consultar en esta pagina y hacer de uno a uno me tomaria mucho tiempo

Comment: Borraste la pregunta de ayer para hacer una nueva???

Comment: Si, señor, es que estoy desesperado, por buscarle una solución a este problema, de antemano pido disculpas

Comment: Perder el avance de ayer no anima a los que vengan voluntariamente a ayudar. Personalmente, no me acuerdo de qué fue lo que puse ayer y me da pereza perder todo de nuevo. Entiende esto: la gente viene voluntariamente a ayudar, gratis, e igual el trabajo que tenemos (el que paga el internet) siempre va a tener prioridad. No es enojo, es sólo tristeza...

Comment: Si tienes razon, por eso pido mil disculpas, por lo sucedido

Comment: O sea.. te dieron una respuesta en una pregunta que borraste solo para volver a publicarla? te das cuenta, que eso provocan pocas ganas de ayudarte, no? que tal si borras esta pregunta, recuperas la pregunta original, le pones una recompensa y tratas de ver si con suerte, @Alfabravo puede ayudarte un poco mas?

Comment: y como lo hago?

Comment: @sebastianvalencia Borrar esta pregunta, ve a la original y darle recuperar pregunta. Y le agregas una recompenza como lo hiciste con esta.

Comment: ya intentaste darle click en el recaptcha desde selenium? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57077202/6999690

Comment: No sé cómo será en VBA, pero en python yo uso `chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` `chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)` `chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])` por si te sirve, por donde empezar a tirar del hilo :)

Comment: Hola Rusian López ya intente darle click al captcha y en ocasiones se vuelve infinito, la solución que me aportas, me la dio alfabravo, pero sera buscar en google alguna solución con lo que me aportaron

Comment: @RuslanLópez no lo he intendado, ya que  el captcha que parece es generado debeido a selenium y en esta pagina no carga captchas, en otras palabras no es algo propio del sitio que estoy consultando

Comment: gracias, S. Wasta  por tu respuesta como comente en otro comentario esa ayuda me la dio Alfabravo, buscare en google como acceder a esas opciones de vba

Comment: @Alfabravo, por favor publica nuevamente la respuesta que me diste, para poder votarla, gracias

Comment: Hola a todos, primero que todo quiero agradecerle a @Alfabravo y a S. Wasta, por darme una idea por donde empezar, aunque borre la pregunta original pude conseguir la solución a mi problema gracias a estos usuarios.

La soluciion fue muy sencilla solo fue usar el metro setProfile de la sigueinte manera:

    driver.SetPreference "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2

con esto quedo solucionando el problema de los captchas

Comment: @sebastianvalencia deberías escribir tu solución como respuesta a tu propia pregunta y aceptarla, para que quede documentado para futuras consultas :)

Comment: si, pero no me parce justo llevarme el credito @Esei, ya que yo borre una pregunta donde me habían ofrecido una respuesta si no la publica la persona pues yo subiré mi respuesta, gracias por tu observación

Answer (score 3, accepted):

primero que todo quiero agradecerle a @Alfabravo y a @S. Wasta, por darme una idea por donde empezar, aunque borre la pregunta original pude conseguir la solución a mi problema gracias a estos usuarios. La solución fue muy sencilla solo fue usar el método setProfile de la siguiente manera:

```
driver.SetPreference "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2
```

donde driver es la variable que use para manejar el navegador y con esto quedo solucionando el problema de los captchas.